# accessing elemets

Tags: query

once i use

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
            $category->addAttributeToSelect('name','parent_id','entity_id','url');
            $category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");
            //$category->load();
```

How do i access 'name','parent_id','entity_id','url' with out using get
I don't want to call the Database as its making my server slow.

Answer (score 0):

to see what attributes (and values) are contained within $category you should use something like:

```
mage::log($category, null, 'mylogfile.log', true);
```

or more primitively:

```
var_dump($category);
```

This will tell you exactly what is within your model.  You can then use magentos magic functions to retrieve certain attributes within your category object.

For example, let's say you used something similar to above to create a $product.  And price is an attribute of product you can use things like this to retrieve that information from the object model:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); <---this is a db call
$price = $product->getPrice() <--- this is not
```

Comment: but getPrice() will be a database call right?

Comment: No, it's a function call against the instantiated product model.

Comment: can you comment here

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/optimizing-code

Comment: Is there any other way other than using "Get"?

Comment: I'll take a look over there.  other than a generic getData($x), I don't think so.  You should check which functions are resulting in db queries because, as described above, things like 'name', 'parentid', and 'price' are usually attributes of the instantiated model and do not result in db queries.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `$category` is actually a collection of categories.
You can access the values like this:

```
foreach ($category as $categoryItem) {
    $entityId = $categoryItem->getId();
    $name[$entityId] = $categoryItem->getName();
    $parentId[$entityId] = $categoryItem->getParentId();
    $url[$entityId] = $categoryItem->getUrl();
}
```

> with out using get I don't want to call the Database as its making my server slow.

you cannot retrieve db values without touching the db.