# optimizing code

Tags: query

When I run

```
$menu = array(
                'items' => array(),
                'parents' => array()
            );
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
            $category->addAttributeToSelect('name','parent_id','entity_id','url');
            $category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");
            $category->load();

            foreach($category as $category1):
            $idcat=$category1->getId();
            $parentcat=$category1->getParentId();
            $menu['items'][$idcat][] = $category1->getUrl();
            $menu['items'][$idcat][] = $category1->getName();
            $menu['items'][$idcat][] = $parentcat;
            $menu['parents'][$parentcat][] = $idcat;
            endforeach;
```

I get a lot of queries in my db

but when when run

```
$menu = array(
                'items' => array(),
                'parents' => array()
            );
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
            $category->addAttributeToSelect('name','parent_id','entity_id','url');
            $category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");
            $category->load();
```

Its much less

Why is that? how do I avoid the "get" functions.

Answer (score 2):

Most of these will be coming from the getUrl since the url is not a feild in this collection and it is really calling a function rather than the magic getter method.

Mage_Catalog_Model_Category

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrlModel()->getCategoryUrl($this);
    }
```

If you want to be more confident that it's not calling a function which itself calls more mysql you can use getData('') instead e.g getData('name') instead of getName().

Comment: If your url follows a standardized template it is possible to derive the url from other methods (setting a variable to the root url and appending the $ID and / or $Name, for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
    $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
    $category->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");
    $categoryArray = $category->toArray();
```